# On activate does not fire with my Modal/Pop-Up form to Requery

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, modal-dialog

I have a modal/pop-up form `frmEditContact` open

on this form there is a combo box full of addresses`cmbAddressList`, populated by a query.
when the user wants to add an address that doesn't exist there is a button that opens the `frmAddress` where they may add an address.

frmAddress allows them to enter an address to the list and gives the option to save, or cancel (both actions close the form after). with this form closed, the focus is now again on frmEditContact

I would like to repopulate the combo box using `docmd.Requery cmbAddressList` after they close the other form

I'm not sure where to handle this, I've tried On Avtivate, On Load, On Update, On Open, On Focus...but none of them fire as I keep the frmEditContact open when they are using the other form

is there a way to keep frmEditContact open the whole time, but still an action Event that will fire so that I can Requery? And does On Activate not work with modal forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can requery the combo from frmAddress  :

```
Forms!frmEditContact.cmbAddressList.Requery
```

I suggest you use the save button to run the requery.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but it doesn't address the root issue. It's disappointing that Access doesn't trigger the `On Activate` event after a popup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `frmEditContact` code.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAddress", acNormal, WindowMode:=acDialog
Me.cmbAddressList.Requery
```

Since `frmAddress` is opened in dialog mode, the next line (`Requery`) will not run until after `frmAddress` is closed.

Comment: +1 because it's a valid approach. It just isn't quite as good as Remou's because it will requery every time frmAddress is closed regardless of `save` or `cancel`.

Comment: @DanielCook Hard-wiring the control reference into frmAddress, as R suggested, works fine as long as frmEditContact is forever the only form which opens frmAddress.  But frmAddress sounds to me like one which might be called from multiple forms.

Comment: @HansUp You make a good point, although in this particular case, frmAddress will only ever be opened from frmEditContact.  I will keep dialog mode in mind in the future though, thanks.